# How to detect collision between two objects at one side only?

Tags: javascript, html, web, canvas

It's like catching an object with a basket. (Bottom part of first object and Top part of second object). This is a sample of my code, but it is detecting all sides.

```
        this.hitPocket = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;  
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
        (mytop > otherbottom) ||
        (myright < otherleft) ||
        (myleft > otherright)) {
          crash = false;
        }

        return crash;
      }
```

**UPDATED:**
Hi Kenneth Mitchell De Leon, i tried your solution and changed the radius into height and width and it worked. My problem now is the basket is movable or draggable to catch the ball. (Sorry that I mentioned it late) So when i drag the basket into the ball it still catches the ball even it did not pass through the top of the basket.

```
function hasContact(basket, ball){
    const hoop = {


        topLeft: {x:basket.x+10, y: basket.y},
            topRight: {x: basket.x+basket.width-10,
                    y: basket.y}
//not necessary if your only concern is the top panel
            // botLeft: {x: basket.position.x,
            //         y: basket.position.y+basket.height},
            // botRight: {x:basket.position.x+basket.width,
        //         y:basket.position.y+basket.height}
    }

    //determine if ball is in between top left or top right of the basket in x axis
    if(ball.x  > hoop.topLeft.x && ball.x+ball.width < hoop.topRight.x 
        //determine if the ball is in contact with top panel of basket in y axis
        && ball.y-basket.y < ball.height/2 && basket.y - ball.y < ball.height/2){
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what about the case of a partial catch? do you want to consider it as a catch? suppose half of the `first box` is inside the `second box`?

Comment: @ArnabRoy it would be nice if I can achieve that partial catch. Need help with that part also. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you update with the description of each object attribute. I am assuming your object looks like this - `var otherobj = { x : 1, y : 1, width : 2, height:2}`. So what does `x and y` represent here? Bottom left corner of the box?

Comment: It is top right/left of the box.

Comment: Sorry, it's top left of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
//point = {x: value, y: value} - assuming this is point object
function hasContact(point1, point2, ball){

    //determine if ball is in between point1 and point2 in x axis
    if(ball.position.x-ball.radius > point1.x && ball.position.x+ball.radius < point2.x 
        //determine if the ball is in contact in y axis
        && ball.position.y-point1.y < ball.radius && point1.y - ball.position.y < ball.radius){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//position 1 is top left
//position 2 is top right
if(hasContact(position1, position2, circle) 
    //use same x coords in position 1 and 2
    //then add y coordinates with the ball/image height-n
    //position 3 is bottom left - just low enough but not more than image/ball height
    //position 5 is bottom right
    && hasContact(position3, position4, circle)){
        //shot is made - do something here....
    }
```

i am assuming something like basketball...

this will return true if the ENTIRE ball is in between left and right edge of the horizontal line, you can adjust it yourself to set it to return true if any part of the ball is in contact with the line. However it will not detect if the ball has passed from one point to another ie(goung through top to bottom);

a bit of information would be more useful...
what kind of collision detectin are you aiming for?

- line and box?
- line and line?
- line and circle? //i assumed this one,i'll edit my answer depending on more info.

I EDITED the function. Just use it twice where the gap is not more than the image/ball height.

Comment: Yes, something like basketball. But it will just stay inside the basket. 

Image to image collision. Thanks!

Comment: my suggestion would be to refactor that function of horizontal collision detection to take to points instead of the object itself thus making a line that detects for the ball and, use the same logic. then just use the function repeatedly One in the top panel of the basket and another on the bottom panel.

Comment: hi @Kenneth, i tried your solution. please see updated.

Comment: ok so my suggestion would be use 2 horizontal line detection... one on top panel and another bellow. if both are true then the image/ball would not just be touching the top panel but would have passed through the top panel enough to get to the second.  the vertical gap between the 2 panels would have to be less than the height of the ball/image. otherwise if the gap is bigger, only one will ever return true. an drawing would make this explanation much simpler.